# How to get these values through get() method?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, get

I have request which return detailod loan fields. How to access fees through get() method to decorate this data?

```
"contract": {
        "contractId": "a46660a3-7963-4610-a5a9-feb02c299e0b",
        "periodInDays": 15,
        "minPartialRepaymentAmount": 250000,
        "maxNumberOfProlongations": 9999,
        "maxOverdueDays": 30,
        "fees": {
            "prolongationAbsoluteFee": [],
            "prolongationPercentageFee": [
                {
                    "calculation": {
                        "rate": 0.8
                    },
                    "name": "Prolongation fee - default",
                    "isCapped": true,
                    "applyFlag": "DEDUCT_DIRECTLY",
                    "minDuration": 0,
                    "maxDuration": 0,
                    "isDefault": true
                }
            ]
        }
    }
```

For example: to get data of Contract I wrote in my DecoratedLoanDetails.ts:

```
class DecoratedDetailedLoan extends Indexable {
  
  constructor(private loan: any) {
    super();
  }

  get contract() {
    return this.loan.contract;
  }
```

This map in my LoanDetails component:

```
{fees ? fees.map((fee: any, index: number) => (
                  <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-inner" key={index}>
                  {contractTermFeesFields.map((item, indexInner) => (
                    <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item" key={indexInner}>
                      <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item__title">
                        {item.title}
                      </div>
                      <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-item__value">
                        {fee[item.key]}
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ))}
                  </div>
                )): null}
```

Answer (score 1):

the same way you access your contract, you can access its fees

```js
class DecoratedDetailedLoan extends Indexable {
  
  constructor(private loan: any) {
    super();
  }

  get contract() {
    return this.loan.contract;
  }

  get fees(){
    return this.loan.contract.fees;
  }
```

I would suggest, since you use typescript, to create an interface that could cast your load input, like that you can access easily the fields you want.

Comment: But when I try it => error occurs: TypeError: fees.map is not a function

Comment: in my LoanDetails component: {fees ? fees.map((fee: any, index: number) => (
                  <div className="ClientLoanDetails__card__content-inner" key={index}>
                  {contractTermFeesFields.map((item, indexInner) => (
                    <div key={indexInner}>
                      <div>
                        {item.title}
                      </div>
                      <div>
                        {fee[item.key]}
                      </div>
                    </div>

Comment: map is used for arrays, but here your fees is a single object.
try to make fees return an array instead,
get fees(){
    return [this.loan.contract.fees];
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use object destructuring like this to get the fees:
`let {fees} = contract;`